# VSCode + MSVC: Unable to open 'throw.cpp' (or exe_common.inl): File not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, vscode-debugger, msvcrt

I am using MSVC+VSCode to compile C++ Program with cl+nmake for comparable operations on gcc+make. The build with nmake seems okay after some trouble with `tasks.json`, `c_cpp_properties.json`, etc. But I encountered problems during debugging, which may involves setup of `launch.json` around `"sourceFileMap"`, but I'm not sure what to do with it properly.
If the program is bug-free, upon exiting it pops `Unable to open 'exe_common.inl': File not found` and if clicking `Create File` it creates an empty file at `{Disk}/a01/...`, a strange directory. If encounters a bug and throw an exception, it pops `Unable to open 'throw.cpp': File not found` and does the same. I suppose it wants to locate the files under `...\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\crt\src\vcruntime` since I could find the files VSCode mentions, but don't know how to address it. I haven't found the very similar posts addressing the solution. How could I get it resolved?

```
# launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "nmake build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppvsdbg",

        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "preLaunchTask": "nmake build active file"
      }
    ]
  }
```

```
# tasks.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "nmake build active file",
        "command": ".vscode\\build.bat",//build.bat invokes the Developer Command Prompt and run cl.exe,
        "args": [

        ],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
          "$msCompile"
        ],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "compiler: cl.exe"
      }
    ]
  }
```

```
# c_cpp_properties.json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${vcpkgRoot}/x86-windows/include"
            ],
            "browse": {},
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.19041.0",
            "compilerPath": "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: There is nothing to solve, you're trying to debug things you don't have the source code for, ignore the error and look higher in the stack trace until you get back into your own code

Comment: As I understood with your comment, it's just VSCode that didn't locate the source code for debugging, and I want to make it relocate to `vcruntime` under VS, to finish the debugging cycle gracefully. Just as you suggested, others recommend ignoring those, saying it's "by design", in terms of `'exe_common.inl'`. I just feel a little uncomfortable with such design, intentionally raise an error in a normal operation. I used to compile with MinGW, which I gave up for packaging building issues. It ends the debugging cycle gracefully, why can't MSVC, the mainstream C++ on Windows?

Comment: Because you don't have the source code, it's not really an error, the debugger is still working it just can't show you the source code for the current stack frame. You'll have the same issue with mingw/libstdc++ in some cases too unless you've built it from source

Comment: I remembered this "some cases" in Mingw, where the session just exit with code 0, without any messages. They may be the same issue, just in different forms, aren't they? I see about the part "the source code for the current stack frame", then just curious, how could I "build it from source", by which I assume is "build debugging from source"?